# Bound on singular value

Tags: matrices, singular-values

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be an antisymmetric matrix. Is there a lower/upper bound or equality relating the two quantities
$$ \min_{u \in \mathbb{C}^d, \lVert u \rVert = 1} \left|u^*Au\right|^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \min_{u \in \mathbb{C}^d, \lVert u \rVert = 1} u^*A^TA u \, ?$$
The right-hand side is the square of the smallest singular value of $A$. Also notice that $u^* A u$ must be pure imaginary while $u^* A^T A u$ must be real.

Indeed, the comment below by Stephen shows that the left-hand side is zero. What about general matrices $A$, not necessarily antisymmetric?

Comment: Both quantities are zero, since you can set $u = 0$.  Maybe you wanted some other condition, like $\|u\| = 1$.  Then the left hand quantity is zero, which you can see by putting in a $u$ all of whose entries are real.

Comment: I forgot to put $\lVert u \rVert = 1$, thank you. What if $A$ is a general matrix, not necessarily antisymmetric? Is there a relationship between the quantities then?

Comment: Since you don't exclude the possibility that $A$ is antisymmetric, you still cannot say anything.

Comment: The left hand side will not necessarily be smaller than the right hand side?

Comment: Oh yes.  I think that is correct.  It should follow from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Stephen for pointing to the Cauchy-Scharz inequality: we have
$$ \left| u^* A u \right|^2 = \left| \left< Au, u \right> \right|^2 \leq \left< Au, Au \right> \left< u, u \right> = u^* A^T A u $$
for normal vector $u$ and real matrix $A$, hence
$$ \min_{u \in \mathbb{C}^d, \lVert u \rVert = 1} \left|u^*Au\right|^2 \leq \min_{u \in \mathbb{C}^d, \lVert u \rVert = 1} u^*A^TA u $$
for any real matrix $A$. The left-hand side is zero for antisymmetric $A$.